# Error while emulating due to dependency conflicts

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I need help. When I am emulating my app, the following error occurs. What can I do?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A032M in debug mode...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).
```

THE IMPORT

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:weather/components/weather_item.dart';
import 'package:weather/constants.dart';
import 'package:weather/ui/detail_page.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
```

Since I only installed that dependency, and it's giving me this error, what can I do?
What can I do in this case to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

ok there is confusionbecause u imported packge or file have name of `ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>` I dont know context of this code but try this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:weather/components/weather_item.dart';
import 'package:weather/constants.dart';
import 'package:weather/ui/detail_page.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart' as modalSheet;
```

And when using it from package tybe this: `modalsheet.code`